# How to modify where clause in query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, where-clause

Below is my current where condition

```
WHERE Log.Event_Type IN ('ABC_CHANGE', 'MAN_ABC_CHANGE')
```

`Event_Type` field has over 20 different data in it.

I only care about `ABC_CHANGE` and `MAN_ABC_CHANGE`.

but I want to modify my where condition.

if `event_type = MAN_ABC_CHANGE` then `Log.Comments like 'Clause:%'`
and if `event_type = ABC_CHANGE` then `Log.Comments is null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
WHERE (log.event_type = 'MAN_ABC_CHANGE' and log.comments like 'Clause:%')
   OR (log.event_type = 'ABC_CHANGE' and log.comments is null)
```

If that is not what you want, it would probably be helpful to post a small test case with sample data that illustrates the problem.